# java - object loses custom properties

Tags: java, object

The custom object "Option" has some methods, which I can call on`optionList.get(1)` , but I can't call on `fragment.getArguments.get(ARG_FIRST_OPTION)` although the latter is of type Option. How can I call them on it?

```
public RecommendationsFragment() {}

public static RecommendationsFragment newInstance(Collection<Option> options) {
    RecommendationsFragment fragment = new RecommendationsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    List<Option> optionList = (List<Option>) options;
    args.putParcelable(ARG_FIRST_OPTION , optionList.get(0));
    args.putParcelable(ARG_SECOND_OPTION , optionList.get(1));
    args.putParcelable(ARG_THIRD_OPTION , optionList.get(2));
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle#get(java.lang.String)) retruns a plain old `Object`. You'll have to down-cast it in order to use `Option`'s methods:

```
((Option) (fragment.getArguments().get(ARG_FIRST_OPTION)).someOptionMethod()
```